# Connect GUI to remote node, wallet & daemon synchronized. Why don't this mean local blockchain is synched?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization, remote-node

I keep having problem in getting local blockchain up to date to current height, including importing downloaded raw blockchain, each time it would get to a point where db gets corrupted & I have to wipe it out to start over. I get 58KB/s download speed from p2p network so I won't ever get synched starting from scratch, and no `--prune-blockchain` or `--sync-pruned-blocks` doesn't help at all.
So after n-th trials, when I got stuck again, I try to connect to remote node from GUI and it said wallet synchronizing & daemon synchronizing. After they're fully synched, I switched back to local node and back to the same crap I started with

```
Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.1.3-release)
Height: 1469833, target: 1469833
```

I thought the point of remote node is to connect to p2p network while synchronizing local blockchain db??

edit: I'll update with the status after an hour as local node

```
>>> status
[19/11/20 10:03] 2020-11-19 03:03:20.276 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.1.3-release)
Height: 1469853/2233672 (65.8%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 446.04 MH/s, v6, 142(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 13m 35s
```

half an hour

```
>>> status
[19/11/20 10:20] 2020-11-19 03:20:21.753 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.1.3-release)
Height: 1469853/2233679 (65.8%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 446.04 MH/s, v6, 269(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 30m 37s
```

instead of prioritize synching local db to close the gap to current height when starting up so *I* as node owner can use it for transaction, I have to keep up with new blocks first. There's literally no incentive for me to run a node if I have to run this 24/7 to be usable.

Comment: What kind of storage medium are you using? Because if it corrupts often, it may be a hardware issue unrelated to the Monero software.

Comment: ZFS mirrored spinning disks & 16GB RAM. These flags`monero-blockchain-import --dangerous-unverified-import=1 --input-file=<path>/Monero/blockchain.raw --data-dir=<path>/Monero/ --resume=true --log-level=1 --db-sync-mode=safe --db-salvage  --batch-size=1 --block-sync-size=1` if i understand it correctly, means that multiple worker in async is off, and inserts txs one by one to db. Used it on `monerod` as well, tried every variations I could think of. Don't think hardware matters much when it's just inserting few kBs each

Comment: `--db-sync-mode=safe` should safe-guard against any corruptions, even if the sync has not completed yet. Do you perhaps have a different storage medium that you could utilize? Then we can check whether the original drive is the root cause of your issue.

Comment: Already did, but not everyone has free 120GB+ SSD just for synching, I ran out of space for SSD because I use it for more important stuff, like OS. Besides, it still doesn't answer why the design isnt well thought. Not only hard to understand how the softwares function (reading errors logs doesn't provide clarity either) already a very high barrier, importing from complete blockchain isn't fool proof enough, plus not ignoring newest blocks on mainnet if the height in local db is lagged. Then it's simply not user node friendly & certainly will progressively much more expensive to run a node.

Comment: i didn't mention that i only used `--dangerous-unverified-import` after completed verifications twice, using it skips the process of verifying 70GB blockchain.raw that took more than half an hour iirc

Comment: I gave up & sold all my monero using remote node. Until it's straight forward & friendly for me to run a node (which means I also can have confidence in using official monero wallet), I don't think I'd consider doing it again. We'll see in a year or two.